# Android Progress Dialog doesn't show

Tags: java, android, user-interface, progressdialog

I want to show a progress dialog while I'm processing some user's request. This is my code and I don't see any good reason why the dialog is not appearing on screen.

```
 public void onGoClick(Button button) {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    try {
        if (invalid) {
           //   Show error message
        } else {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.user_wait_message));
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();

            //  Do processing
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

When I move the ProgressDialog declaration statement inside the try block and removes the dismiss method from finally block,  I'm able to see the circular dialog on the screen, but when I change it like the above code, nothing comes on the screen. There is no async calls in the processing area, that's why I don't find anything buggy here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yup the good looks good, invalid must be true

Comment: I guess its some exception rises. Try to debug it.

Comment: @marsje the else block is executing.

Comment: I've tried debugging it, the else block is executing.

Comment: On a side note, you will encounter a Null Pointer Exception using your current approach if invalid is true, because you never initalize `progressDialog`, meaning you're running `null.dismiss();` in your finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Your Progress dialog is shown and then immediately dismissed. 
The finally block is executed directly after the try block.

Try to add an [OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) to verify this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is very weird as **clean and build** worked for me. I don't know if it's a bug in Android Studio (1.2) or something else. I really appreciate your answers as it was very helpful and I've learned a lot of things about async in android :)